# http request with arraylist fails

Tags: c#, arraylist, uwp, win-universal-app

I am performing a http request and passing an arraylist to a formUrlEncoded property but this fails

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SubmitInspection(
       TruckRegistrationDetails truckdetails
        List<CommentModel> check_comments, 
        String general_comment)
{
    var body= new ArrayList(){ truckdetails, check_comments, general_comment };
    var body = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body); //this fails
    //get url from SQLite
    var response = await http.PostAsync(url, body);
    return response;
}
```

Am getting an error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

How do I add the passed different parameter types to formUrlEncoded

Comment: Aside from the error, you need to know exactly what to pass to the PostAsync method. It has to be in a fomat that the receiver can work with. You then need to pass one or more key-value pairs to the PostAsyn method in an array or something which implements IEnumerable. Have you got any requirements as to what you need to pass and the format?

Comment: I see @CodingYoshi the receiver is php which expects an array or an object

Answer (score 0):

You need to post FormUrlEncodedContent

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"<your key>", "<your value>"},
    {"<your next key>", "<your next value>"},
    ...
});
```

Then with your HttpClient instance, post it

```
var message =
    await httpClient.PostAsync(_url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In your case, you are going to most likely need to transform what you are getting in your SubmitInspection method to whatever the you are posting to.

Answer (score 0):

You should build `Dictionary<string,string>` :

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
....
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    values.Add("truckdetails",  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(truckdetails));
    values.Add("check_comments", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(check_comments));
    values.Add("general_comment", general_comment);
    var body = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = await http.PostAsync(url, body);
    return response;
```

and don't forget to add reference to `System.Web.Extensions`

**Update:**

for serializing in `UWP` use [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). so instead of:

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(truckdetails)
```

use:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(truckdetails)
```

I hope be helpful :)

Comment: System.Web.Extensions is not available in uwp

Comment: so you can use JSON.NET (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serializing the objects in UWP.

Comment: You cannot just pass any random structure to the PostAsync method. It has to be in a format and structure that the receiver can work with.

Comment: It is not random! It is a `Dictionary<string, string>` which contains Named-Value set and each value is a valid json format or plain text string.

Comment: I get that but how do you know the receiver is expecting Json?

Comment: If worked and the problem solved, Don't forget making accept the anwser.

Answer (score 0):

This is the signature for the constructor of `FormUrlEncodedContent`:

```
public FormUrlEncodedContent(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nameValueCollection)
```

As you see it needs an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>` but you are giving it an `ArrayList` so it starts to complain and say:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Just give it what it needs by building `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

Right now your arraylist contains `TruckRegistrationDetails`, a `List<Comment>` and a `String`. You need to figure out what you will pass from this as key-value pairs.